# Can not download uploaded file from web server(OTA)

Tags: blackberry

I have deployed my .cod , .html, and .htaccess file on the web server for blackberry application distribution having size of 237kb but it does not allow to download.
What is the proper way to upload it?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add more detail to your question. What doesn't work? What error messages do you get?

Comment: IT gives error like no such http connection or file is to large to download in blackberry mobile

Comment: You need a .jad file, and point your browser to this file.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a nice Tutorial on how to do it :

http://assets.handango.com/marketing/developerTeam/BlackBerryOTADeployment.pdf

All you have to do is build the application with the [eclipse plugin](http://na.blackberry.com/eng/developers/javaappdev/javaplugin.jsp) that you installed from RIM.

1. From eclipse you package the project

   1.1 Right click on the project

   1.2 BlackBerry

   1.3 Package
2. Then go to the folder deliverables

   2.1 Go to the folder with your version,mine is 5.0.0

   2.2 Extract the application jar

   2.3 Take the *.cod files(there should more than one if the app is bigger than 64k) and the .jad file and put it on your webserver
3. now you point your BlackBerry browser to the .jad file and install your new app

Don't forget to sign your application if needed.

Answer (score -1):

Usually the problem because the jad file can't find the jar and cod files.
Are you sure you have pointed it to the absolute path of the jar.
instead of writing RIM-COD-URL : myApp.Jar you should write it : http://www.mydomain.com/myfolderlocation/myApp.jar

and so for the other file.

And don't forget to rename the COD to zip file and extract the zip file contents(which contain COD files) and upload these files. just remove the zip file after that

Comment: The path should be relative not absolute.